# In swift NSNetService class how to send data using getInoutStream

Tags: swift, nsnetservice

Currently I am working on a program in which i am connecting two IOS devices using NSNetService class. I am able to connect both the devices but i don't know how to send data using  getInoutStream function. Can any buddy help me.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [multipeer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/)? It's a much simpler solution to what you're trying to do. Also NSNetService has a few known bugs. However, you send data between the two by setting up a Bonjour connection on NSNetService. The getInputStream method requires arguments of the type UnsafeMutablePointer:

```
    public func getInputStream(inputStream: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSInputStream?>, outputStream: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSOutputStream?>) -> Bool

var inputStream : NSInputStream?
var outputStream : NSOutputStream?

let success = service.getInputStream(&inputStream, outputStream: &outputStream)
```

Then just write data using a memory stream and it'll get passed to the listener port.

This is the finished code:

This function initiates the connection on 127.0.0.1

```
func initNetworkCommunication(){
    var host : CFString = "127.0.0.1"
    var port : UInt32 = 7001
    var readstream : Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
    var writestream : Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, host, port, &readstream, &writestream)

    inputstream = readstream!.takeRetainedValue()
    outputstream = writestream!.takeRetainedValue()

    inputstream.delegate = self
    outputstream.delegate = self


    inputstream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    outputstream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    inputstream.open()
```

And this is for the stream IO:

```
func stream(aStream: NSStream, handleEvent eventCode: NSStreamEvent) { //This is the stream IO function. It allows RW of the stream
        switch (eventCode){
    case NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred:
        NSLog("ErrorOccurred")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered:
        NSLog("EndEncountered")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.None:
        NSLog("None")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:
        NSLog("HasBytesAvaible")
        var buffer = [UInt8](count: 4096, repeatedValue: 0)
        if ( aStream == inputstream){

            while (inputstream.hasBytesAvailable){
                var len = inputstream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count) 
                if(len > 0){
                    var output = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: buffer.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) 
                    if (output != ""){
                        NSLog("server said: %@", output!)
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.allZeros:
        NSLog("allZeros")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.OpenCompleted:
        NSLog("OpenCompleted")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.HasSpaceAvailable:
        NSLog("HasSpaceAvailable")
        break
   default:
        // default code here
        break
  }
```

Comment: Thank's for the reply. I have done all these things but I want to send message between both the devices, so what should I do??

Comment: @AvinashMulewa I told you. Use a memory stream and just write to 'success'.

Comment: I am beginner in swift can you please send me the code.

Comment: @AvinashMulewa I will this once, but Stack Overflow is a community of finding answers to issues, not completed code. I will update my answer and get back to you.

Comment: @AvinashMulewa My pleasure. Please remember that Stack Overflow is for answers, not code (however, we are happy to help whenever we can). Please mark this as answered for future reference. Happy coding :-)

Comment: @AvinashMulewa FYI: It's also generally not good practice to use `default` case in Swift for debugging purposes, otherwise you lose any errors or issues the compiler gives you at runtime from the switch statement.

Comment: this is for connected iPhone app to any device that listen to port and host (computer for example) ? and transfer files ?